# Update specific records based on some group

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using `SQL Server 2008 R2`.

I am having a database table that contains some user data as given below :

```
Id  UserId  Sys     Dia     ReadingType     DataId              IsDeleted
1   10      98      65      last            1390556024216       0
2   10      99      69      average         1390556024216       0
3   10      102     96      last            1390562788540       0
4   10      102     96      average         1390562788540       0
5   11      130     98      last            1390631241547       0
6   11      130     98      average         1390631241547       0
7   2       285     199     first           1390770562374       0
8   2       250     180     last            1390770562374       0
9   2       267     189     average         1390770562374       0
10  1       258     180     first           1391191009457       0
11  1       258     180     last            1391191009457       0
12  1       258     180     average         1391191009457       0
13  1       285     199     additional      1391191009457       0
14  22      110     78      last            1391549208338       0
15  22      123     83      last            1391549208349       0
```

In this table, there are records that are having the `same DataId` but `different ReadingType`.

I want to set `IsDeleted=1` for the records having `ReadingType='last'` and having a record with `ReadingType='average'` with the `same DataId, Sys, Dia and UserId`.

So the Desired result shoul be :

```
Id  UserId  Sys     Dia     Reading         DataId              IsDeleted
1   10      98      65      last            1390556024216       0
2   10      99      69      average         1390556024216       0
3   10      102     96      last            1390562788540       1
4   10      102     96      average         1390562788540       0
5   11      130     98      last            1390631241547       1
6   11      130     98      average         1390631241547       0
7   2       285     199     first           1390770562374       0
8   2       250     180     last            1390770562374       0
9   2       267     189     average         1390770562374       0
10  1       258     180     first           1391191009457       0
11  1       258     180     last            1391191009457       1
12  1       258     180     average         1391191009457       0
13  1       285     199     additional      1391191009457       0
14  22      110     78      last            1391549208338       0
15  22      123     83      last            1391549208349       0
```

Here the records with `Id 3, 5 and 11` should be `marked as deleted` as they are `having same UserId, Sys, Dia, DataId and ReadingType="last" with another record having ReadingType="average" with same other fields`.

Can anyone help me how to find out such a records and update them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use UPDATE with EXISTS subquery:

```
UPDATE T   
  SET IsDeleted=1
      WHERE
           ReadingType='last'  
           AND 
           EXISTS(SELECT * FROM T as T1 
                    WHERE T1.ReadingType='average'
                          AND T1.DataId=T.DataId
                          AND T1.Sys=T.Sys
                          AND T1.Dia=T.Dia
                          AND T1.UserId=T.UserId
                   )
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64a56/1)</kbd>

Comment: Thank a lot. It worked fine for me. :) +1 for your kind answer.

Answer (score -1):

You Can solve many way but here i am using the sub-query to solve your problem

```
UPDATE TABLE SET IsDeleted=1
       WHERE DataId=(SELECT DataId FROM TABEL WHERE Reading='last')
```

Comment: Dude, before you post any answer just check your query once. Do you think the sub-query will return only DataId? The error will be prone here. Again, If you select only DataId from sub-query then also it will set IsDeleted=1 for all of the records. I am downgrading your answer.